# print data to csv file form an array

Tags: perl, export-to-csv

I tried to print an array to a csv file, and to do this write this code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new();

my $file = "data.csv";

open(OUT, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";

my @columns = (qw/what ever the items are for each columns/);

my $status = $csv->print(OUT, \@columns);
```

And this script return me this:
Bareword "OUT" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at test.pl line 37.
Execution of test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

I try to use Text::CSV or Text::CSV_XS to print data in csv and i need more information about syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use bareword filehandles as subroutine parameters. Use lexical filehandles instead:

```
open my $out, '<', $file or die ...;
$csv->print($out, \@columns);
```

Or, use the typeglob sigil (less preferable):

```
$csv->print(*OUT, \@columns);
```

Moreover, you opened the file for reading (`<`). You can't print to an input filehandle. Did you mean `>`?